# How can I create multiple files in the current directory in bash?

Tags: shell, files

Is there a command to create multiple files in the current directory? i.e. if I would like to create `__init__.py`, `views.py`, `models.py` and `admin.py` as follows:

```
> COMMAND __init__.py views.py models.py admin.py
```

What would `COMMAND` be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`touch __init__.py views.py models.py admin.py`

Comment: I'm accepting this answer over binfalses because it's more general purpose.

Answer (score 12):

```
touch {__init__,views,models,admin}.py
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `touch` is probably the most generally accepted way to accomplish this, but in some shells such as `zsh` there is something called "multiple stream output redirection" which would allow you do do something like this:

```
> __init__.py > views.py > models.py > admin.py
```

..all as one command. If you use globs as suggested by [binfalse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11932/bash-a-command-to-create-multiple-files-in-the-current-directory/11935#11935) you don't need to repeat the output operator:

```
> {__init__,views,models,admin}.py
```

This is often useful if you want to start all files out with a few common items like their hash-bang and maybe some includes. I often `head` some other script and redirect it to several files like this if I'm going to write a couple new gigs.